# default value when adding new item of date field

Tags: 7, entities

i'm using drupal 7 and in my content type there is a date field has start and end value with unlimited values, i set the default value to "Now".
but the problem is when adding new item of this field there is no default value in it.

is there a way to set a default value for new items?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you ever discover a solution to this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: not yet :( sory ... let me know if you fine some one

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
//this hook or general hook_field_widget_form_alter
function hook_field_widget_date_popup_form_alter(&$element, $form_state, &$context){

  //only when field is specific name and during node creation form
  if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_date' && !isset($element['#entity']->nid)) {

    //if default value is not set, only for second and later elements, when first item value is set
    if (!is_array($element['#default_value']) && $element['#delta'] > 0 && isset($form_state['values']['field_date']['und'][$element['#delta']-1]['value'])) {

      //set value
      $element['#default_value'] = array(
        //advance by 24 hours
        'value' => $form_state['values']['field_date']['und'][$element['#delta']-1]['value'] + 24 * 3600,
        //same timezone
        'timezone' => $form_state['values']['field_date']['und'][$element['#delta']-1]['timezone'],
        'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
        'date_type' => 'datestamp',
      );

      //if second value (date to) is set (by comparing value and value2)
      if ($form_state['values']['field_date']['und'][$element['#delta']-1]['value2'] != $form_state['values']['field_date']['und'][$element['#delta']-1]['value'])
        //set and advance second value by 24 hours also
        $element['#default_value']['value2'] = $form_state['values']['field_date']['und'][$element['#delta']-1]['value2'] + 24 * 3600;

      //#date_items needs to be same as #default_value
      $element['#date_items'] = $element['#default_value'];
    }
  }
}
```